# Installing FirebaseUI-ios via Swift Package Manager

Tags: xcode, firebaseui, swift-package-manager

I'm attempting to install the FirebaseUI-iOS using the Swift Package Manager. I've tried with both Xcode 14.0 and Xcode 13.4.1. I get the following errors: [image: errors with Xcode `13.4.1]

[![errors with Xcode 14.0][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FklqL.png

I've tried with using the "Up to Major version", a specific version, nothing is working. Does anyone have a suggestion? If I look in the repo, the Package.swift files do exist. I filed an issue on this, as well. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/1094

TIA

Answer (score 5):

Finally figured it out.
You need to set the version to 12.0.0 even though the default suggested one is 0.6.1. You can do that by selecting your Xcode project > Package Dependencies > FirebaseUI-iOS.

[image]